# How can I insert a button on top of a glSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I was trying to draw a UI on top of a GLSurface view, but I can't figure out what's the best way to do it.

I read this post [Drawing Android UI on top of GLSurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254320/drawing-android-ui-on-top-of-glsurfaceview) , but the code ins't there for me to check it.

The way to do it in the xml layout file?

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
have you tried these 2 links?

[how to build a GUI/HUD over top a glSurfaceView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596778/how-to-build-a-gui-hud-over-top-a-glsurfaceview-in-android)
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11143/is-it-possible-to-overlay-edittext-box-on-a-glsurfaceview-on-android

They seems to address the very same point you are asking for.

This other one works as a charm in my experience, it is about having admob on top of a GLSurfaceView but the concept remains the same:

[Android: how to display admob ads on GLSurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689484/android-how-to-display-admob-ads-on-glsurfaceview)

I hope to have helped.

Maurizio